# Sort folders by name

Tags: sorting, unix

I would like to sort a list of subfolders contained in a folder, according to the name in an increasing manner:

Ex: folder names:

```
TF_list_to_test10679   
TF_list_to_test1062  
TF_list_to_test1078  
...
```

Desired output:

```
TF_list_to_test1062  
TF_list_to_test1078  
TF_list_to_test10679  
...
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Are you looking to do that programmatically? Or in a shell? Or where?

Comment: Do you want to sort alphabetically or by length? If the former, why is 1078 above 10679?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in shell Unix. i would like to sort just by increasing number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work if you don't have file names with tabs:

```
find . -type d | sed 's/[[:digit:]]*$/&\t&/' | sort -nk 2 | cut -f 1
```